# Proving the distance between centroid and orthocentre is twice the distance from centroid to circumcentre.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with right angle at $C$. First find the circumcentre, $O$, the centroid $G$, and the orthocentre $H$ of triangle ABC. Then prove that these three points are collinear and that $HG = 2GO$. All advice appreciated.

Comment: The $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Then $H=C$, $O=M$ and $G$ lies at $\frac{1}{3}$ of the median $CM$.

Answer (score 0):

The midpoints of $AB,\,BC,\,CA$ are the vertices of the *median triangle*, which also has centroid $G$. We get from $\triangle ABC$ to its median triangle by a $-1/2$ scaling centred on $G$. This maps $H$ to the median triangle's orthocentre. Each side of $\triangle ABC$ is a chord of its circmcircle, and their perpendicular bisectors meet at $O$. In particular, the bisection is at the median triangle's vertices. Therefore, $O$ is the median triangle's orthocentre.

Answer (score 0):

Let triangle be $\Delta ABC$ and orthocenter be $H$ , centroid be $G $and circumcenter be $O$.
We use the property that in $\Delta$$ABC$ let $AG$ meet  $BC$ at $D$ then $AG:GD = 2:1$

> **Construction**
>
> - Let the line $AH$ meet $BC$ at    $ F$
> - Draw a perpendicular from $O$ to $BC$ which will meet the line $BC$ at $D$ (since perpendicular from the centre of circle bisects the chord)
>
> **Proving**
>
> Now In $\Delta AGH$ and $\Delta DGO.$
>
> $\angle ODG$ $=$$\angle HAG.$
>   (Alternate angles between parallel line $OD$ and $AH$ where $OH$ transversal)
>
> $\angle DGO$$ =$$\angle AGH.$
>   (Opposite angles )
>
> Thus $\Delta AGH$ $\sim$ $\Delta DGO.$
>
> Therefore $\dfrac{AG}{DG}$$=$$\dfrac{GH}{GO}$
>
> Since $\dfrac{AG}{DG}$$=$$\dfrac12$
>
> Hence we prove $\dfrac{GH}{GO}$$=$$\dfrac12$.